# Android: Deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

After update Cordova to v6.4.0 and Android platform to 6.0.0, my app don't work any more. I'm getting this:

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1223
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady cordova.js:1216
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady cordova.js:1216
```

I tried to remove all plugins and add it one by one. I found that is a problem with cordova-plugin-device and cordova-plugin-network-information. All my plugins are up to date

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue...

Comment: That was on mac, now I'm trying on a PC, and is worst...

Comment: The problem is with those plugins (cordova-plugin-device && cordova-plugin-network-information).   Those plugins fire the `onCordovaInfoReady` and `onCordovaConnectionReady` "channels" respectively.  If they don't fire, then `deviceready` doesn't fire.

Must be something that changed in cordova-android 6.0.0, which is preventing those plugins from firing their channels...

Comment: @asgeo1 do you know if is already reported on cordova issues?

Comment: I couldn't see anything. I've since downgraded to cordova-android 5.2.2, and that seems to work OK, even with cordova 6.4.0. Maybe try that for now.

Comment: @asgeo1 what about iOS, i'm getting white screen, I tried fallback to iOS 4.2.1 and is still happening..

Comment: Not sure, I'm not having that issue. It's working OK for me with cordova-ios 4.3.0.   I'd say that's a separate, unrelated issue.  Check your console for errors, and make sure your `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag is set correctly - esp make sure you've added `gap://ready` as that is now required.

Comment: Ionic guys say that I should remove the CSP meta tag...wich one I should use?

Comment: You're right, was not related..some ionic problem, but not the CSP meta tag

Comment: @SebastiánRojas are you by chance using crosswalk? I just came across this as I am experiencing the same issue following installation of cordova-android 6.0.0. The solutions says the npm version is missing patch a patch and they suggest installing from the github repo https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7422

Comment: ionic team suggests to uninstall & reinstall all plugins & platform and thread is locked for discussion https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/259, that's a quite bit of work and not a solution to the problem thru'

Answer (score 9):

If you happen to be running the Crosswalk plugin in your app I just confirmed that uninstalling it and reinstalling via;

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

Gets rid of

`deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1223
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady cordova.js:1216
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady cordova.js:1216`

You can see the issue at Crosswalk's Jira issue listing here.

https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7422

Comment: When switching to cordova android 6.0.0 the primary bridge was changed to the EVAL_BRIDGE.
Crosswalk adds that support in version 2.2.0 https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/commit/f6d1ef308a50dcc0669ea78b72ba3570ae3a2b8b

Answer (score 7):

Solution:

put the call "cordova.js" to the last line in the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Greeting...

Comment: I was facing similar issue in my Cordova ios application.After struggling a lot, finally this solution did the magic. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This should be fixed in cordova-android 6.1.0. It has not been added to the npm-registry yet, so you can use it by placing this to your config.xml:

`<engine name="android" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.git#6.1.0"/>`

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna wait the official release

Comment: 6.1.0!! a lot or bugs I supose...so bad, cordova makes me lost 3 days

Comment: I just updated to 6.1.0 via command line `platform remove` and `platform add`. It fixed an issue with seeing the default Cordova icon as my splash screen instead of the one I had setup. But the splash screen doesn't hide unless I force the app to the background and then re-open it. Also the `deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds` and `Channel not fired:` for `onCordovaInfoReady` and `onFileSystemPathsReady` messages continue to show up in my console.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was fighting issues with icons, splashscreens, deviceReady events, push notifications, and much much more on Android.  I went with 6.1.1 and thsi fixed everything!

Comment: Is there any specific location to add this line in config.xml

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan There is not, I normally add it to the end of the config `<engine name="android" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.git#6.1.0"/>
</widget>`

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered this same issue on iOS. Eventually what worked for me was a simple `remove` and `add` of the `ios` platform:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

It had been quite a while since I had completely re-built the `ios` platform and, just like you, I had made other major changes during that time (Cordova upgrade, XCode upgrade, etc). My theory is that my `config.xml` or existing `ios` build was somehow incompliant with the latest Cordova requirements. Doing a `platform remove` and `platform add` will clear out the build files and update `config.xml`.

I doubt this applies to the OP, but for others who've encountered this same issue, please ensure that you've included `cordova.js` in your `index.html` file. If you've not done so, add this line:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

It's a very common omission when just getting started with Cordova.

Answer (score 3):

Update your cordova-android.

I updated cordova-android to 10.1.0 and didn't have this problem any more.

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@10.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you included cordova.js on the bottom of the body of your index.html

And don't ever forget about the `type="text/javascript"` that need to be located along with `src=""`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also include this meta tags on the html head

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Then remove the current installed platform and then add it again

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform remove browser
cordova platform remove ios

cordova platform add android
cordova platform add browser
cordova platform add ios
```

Serve it then refresh your browser or build it

If that doesn't solve your problem, then try remove some plugin one by one or remove your scripts to find out the bugs..

Comment: Why is `type="text/javascript"` required (it should be the default?) and required in a certain order?

Comment: @Luke As I remember it's required to help the browser to recognize the external script as `text/javascript` in case if the server send incorrect `content-type`. At that time I was using Phonegap from PlayStore as a client for testing on real device and my problem was fixed by doing that, and debugging on real device was difficult. About the order, I will edit my English regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the real reason of this issue,
But I tried removing `cordova-plugin-whitelist` and `cordova-plugin-device` from the plugins list and added them again.
luckily that solved the issue,

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing on iphone , the problem is related to 
Content-Security-Policy , either remove it , or change the rules so it can run !

Also make sure cordova.js is added to the end of the html file .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this with cordova-android 10.1.2, where it should have been fixed, I guess. Removing and re-adding the android platform didn't help, either.

(FWIW: I'm using cordova via [Quasar (v1)](https://v1.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/configuring-cordova), and I observed that the `quasar dev -m cordova` *live* mode (with HMR) worked, but the "regular" `quasar build`/`cordova run` deploys didn't.)

What "fixed" it, for whatever reason, was this change to `config.xml`, [suggested by user judevian in a ionic webview issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/600#issuecomment-771246329):

> So if u defined it like this:

```xml
<preference name="Scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="Hostname" value="localhost" />
```

> Also set

```xml
<allow-navigation href="http://app/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://app/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://localhost/*"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For someeone (like me) who would not like to downgrade Cordova, please follow my guide (I successfully did after a whole day trying):

- Back up your current (cordova root, not platforms/android) project.
- Open cordova CLI from root: `cordova platform remove android`
- After removing: `cordova platform add android`. Your package project (structure) folders are **kept**, so don't worry.
- `cordova plugin ls` and then remove every cordova plugin execpt Notfication and Whitelist (Cordova's default installed plugins).
- Use `cordova plugin add <plugin-id>` to add back your using plugins one by one.
- Go back to you backup-ed folder: Clone back `AndroidManifest.xml` and everything in `app/src/main`. This includes: **assets**, **java**, **libs** and **res**. One file you only need (actually I suggest) to leave out is **res/xml/config.xml**. Do **not** clone this. Let Cordova build later.
- Cordova CLI (from root cordova project, not platforms/android): `cordova build android`
- If you have any 3rd party plugins, or using different content src, properties, please copy them (features, content src, author,...) back into `app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml` . Cordova won't be able to detect your 3rd plugin
- Open Android Studio, import your "repaired" project --> Make project, then Run App. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Visual Studio and have this error in the Chrome emulator. I found that firing up the Web Inspector would allow Visual Studio to prompt for some of the hooks that various plugins were asking for, and clicking through the various popups got me past this. It must be something to do with the way that Visual Studio sets up the Cordova Plugin Simulation, but with my setup it was getting blocked from presenting the popups.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still relevant to anyone:

What worked for me was removing and then adding again a plugin, namely, "katzer
cordova-plugin-local-notifications".

Answer (score 0):

in my case my working project suddenly stopped and displayed above error

My project started work

1 . uninstall mobile debug api

2 . Clear project folder

For android users

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

or

```
gradlew clean
```

for ios users

```
cd ios
xcodebuild clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by putting the right middleware to provide plugin files in the server.
Check if you forgot it even though you need it.

```
app.use("plugin location", (req, res) => res.sendFile("plugin location"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I added below preference in config.xml and it worked for me.

I have updated my project to Cordova 11

Comment: You must specifically say which preferences that you added and by which user by his name. 

Better way is, you must specify the preferences you added in your answer. Since later what happens if the other user may edited his answer and changed its content.