# Meteor Cordova Android deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: cordova, meteor, plugins

When I run my meteor cordova app on android, it takes a real long time to startup.The splashscreen stays on-screen at least 7 seconds, and I get the 
error:

> I20170120-15:42:58.835(-8) (cordova.js:1185) deviceready has not fired
>   after 5 seconds. I20170120-15:42:58.836(-8) (cordova.js:1178) Channel
>   not fired: onDOMContentLoaded

Since this is cordova buried in meteor, I don't have the options as suggested in some of the other posts.  I have tried ideas in:

[Android: Deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352905/android-deviceready-has-not-fired-after-5-seconds)

https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/772

(and more I can't post)

But have not had positive results.  Is this still an issue with Meteor?  I am using Meteor version 1.4.2.3.

The plugin list (package name removed) is:

```
"installed_plugins": {
    "cordova-plugin-console": {
    },
    "cordova-plugin-device": {
    },
    "cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp": {
    },
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {
    },
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {
    },
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
    },
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": {
    },
    "phonegap-plugin-push": {
    }
},
```

Actual error:

> I20170124-18:15:24.365(-8) (android://localhost:12936/cordova.js:1185)
>   deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. I20170124-18:15:24.368(-8)
>   (android://localhost:12936/cordova.js:1178) Channel not fired:
>   onDOMContentLoaded

Running on an Android device:

> I20170124-18:15:20.053(-8)? INFO onConnection:
>   192.168.0.225:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SAMSUNG-SM-T337A Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
>   Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Safari/537.36

I have removed and re-added plugins platforms as suggested in some of the posts, but have not been able to get around this issue.  There are a lot of posts on the issue, but they have not been applicable, or just didn't work for me.

Not sure what to do next, have been plugging away at this for days, going in circles.

PS:  my package list is:

```
Meteor 1.4.2.3
(18:21 krivacic@littlezip app) > meteor list
accolver:twilio-meteor         1.10.1  Twilio API Wrapper for Meteor
accounts-password              1.3.3  Password support for accounts
accounts-ui                    1.1.9  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
alanning:roles                 1.2.15  Authorization package for Meteor
aldeed:collection2             2.10.0  Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the client and server.
aldeed:simple-schema           1.5.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 and autoform.
andrasph:clockpicker           0.0.2  Clockpicker (v0.0.6), a clock-style timepicker for Bootstrap, from Wang Shenwei
arillo:flow-router-helpers     0.5.2  Template helpers for flow-router
cordova:cordova-plugin-device  1.1.4
dburles:factory                1.1.0  Factories for Meteor
ecmascript                     0.6.1  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
es5-shim                       4.6.15  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
harrison:papa-parse            1.1.1  A powerful, in-browser CSV parser for big boys and girls
http                           1.2.10  Make HTTP calls to remote servers
jplack:bootstrap-timepicker    0.2.2  Bootstrap 3 timepicker for Meteor.
kadira:blaze-layout            2.3.0  Layout Manager for Blaze (works well with FlowRouter)
kadira:flow-router             2.12.1  Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor
lookback:emoji                 0.3.1  Easily render and manage emojis in Meteor.
matb33:collection-hooks        0.8.4  Extends Mongo.Collection with before/after hooks for insert/update/remove/find/findOne
mikowals:batch-insert          1.1.14  Insert multiple documents to mongo collection with one db call.
percolate:synced-cron          1.3.2  Allows you to define and run scheduled jobs across multiple servers.
practicalmeteor:chai           2.1.0_1  The Chai Assertion Library, v2.1.0
practicalmeteor:faker          3.0.1_1  Generate massive amounts of fake data in node.js and in the browser.
practicalmeteor:mocha          2.4.5_6  Write package tests with mocha and run them in the browser or from the command line with spacejam.
practicalmeteor:sinon          1.14.1_2  Standalone test spies, stubs and mocks for JavaScript.
raix:push                      3.0.2  Isomorphic Push notifications for APN and GCM
reactive-dict                  1.1.8  Reactive dictionary
remcoder:chronos               0.5.0  Reactive time utilities. Includes reactive replacements for new Date(), Date.now() and moment()
shell-server                   0.2.1  Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command.
simple:json-routes             2.1.0  The simplest way to define server-side routes that return JSON
standard-app-packages          1.0.9  Moved to meteor-platform
standard-minifier-css          1.3.2  Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js           1.2.1  Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
templates:tabs                 2.3.0  Reactive tabbed interfaces compatible with routing.
twbs:bootstrap                 3.3.6  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
xolvio:cleaner                 0.3.1  Gives you methods to clear your Mongo database and collections for testing purposes
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?